# Is elasticquent/elasticquent is compatible with laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Adding elasticquent/elasticquent to my laravel 7 with line in composer.json

```
"elasticquent/elasticquent": "dev-master"
```

I got errors :

```
$ composer update 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2
    - Installation request for elasticquent/elasticquent dev-master -> satisfiable by elasticquent/elasticquent[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - elasticquent/elasticquent dev-master requires illuminate/database ~4.2|^5|^6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev], illuminate/database[4.2.x-dev, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - laravel/framework 7.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev].
```

I am not sure, but seems elasticquent/elasticquent is not compatible with laravel 7 ?

Ar least here https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent I do not see any reference to laravel 7...
Can elasticquent be used in   laravel 7 ?

In my app :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
```

In my OS I have :

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
```

Thanks!

Comment: elasticsearh version has nothing to do with laravel version, it has more to do with which php version are you running, if elasticsearch package that you use supports php > 7  then you are good to go!

Comment: I added versions in my post. Is iy the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem you need to check the composer file of the Elasticquent.

https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/blob/master/composer.json#L21

At this line, according to the library requirements, you need to use "~4.2|^5|^6" these versions of the database library of laravel. But Laravel 7, using higher version of database library. You can see here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/composer.json#L57

So, you can create a pull request or create an issue to Elasticquent to make this library to be compatible with Laravel 7 version.

Edit:

According to [@matchish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600992/matchish), there is another library that is compatible with ES7 and Laravel 7, 8 :

https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch

Comment: I wrote a request at  Elasticquent forum. Are there some replacement of Elasticquent ? Are they better or worse ?

Comment: As I know, there are several libraries for elasticsearch at laravel ecosystem. Here some of them: https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver, https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch, etc.  But I can not say that one of them is the best. They are have their own features. You need to check their features and you need to select one of them according to your scenario.

Comment: I used Babenkoivan's library beafore with ES6. And It had helped me a lot to handle full text search easily.

Comment: This one compatible with laravel 7 https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch and ES7.6 including

Comment: I added answer. And Thank you for the library. I think it is the library that you are developing it.

Comment: Anymore, https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch this library supporting ES8, too.